# Symfony - RuntimeException: Unknown key "class" for annotation "@FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\View"

Tags: web-services, rest, symfony, doctrine, fosrestbundle

I want to create web service rest with symfony2,
I'm installed SerializerBundle & FOSRestBundle
when i trying the commande  `php app/console router:debug`
 for this purpose but I am getting the following error.

```
[RuntimeException]                                                                 
  Unknown key "class" for annotation "@FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\View".
```

The class View exist.

```
<?php

namespace Sdz\AdminBundle\Controller;

use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\View;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;

use Sdz\VoyageBundle\Entity\Promo;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class RestpromoAction extends Controller
{    
    /**
     * @View("restpromo",class="SdzVoyageBundle:Promo")
     * @ParamConverter()
     */
    public function getPromorestAction(Promo $entitysPromo)
    {
        return array('restpromo'=>$entitysPromo);
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You have added the "class" parameter to `@View` instead of `@ParamConverter`.

This is the faulty line:

```
@View("restpromo",class="SdzVoyageBundle:Promo")
```

Add the variable-name and corresponding class to your `@ParamConverter` to resolve your issue.

```
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as FOSRest;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration as SensioFrameworkExtra;

/**
 * @FOSRest\View()
 * @SensioFrameworkExtra\ParamConverter(
 *     "promo",
 *     class="SdzVoyageBundle:Promo"
 * )
 */
public function getPromorestAction(Promo $promo)
{
    return array(
        'restpromo' => $promo
    );
}
```